# How to check column values in talend tmap?

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, talend

In talend DI, tmap component, I need to pass value to target file from source when a another column value is not between 53 and 100 and another column value is not equal to "POOL".
I need to check these conditions. Can anyone help to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

In Filter section of target schema in tMap component, write

(row1.column2 > 53 && row1.column2 < 100) && (!row1.column3.equals("POOL"))

and assign row1.column1 to target schema column.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Sorry I shd not give this to target schema component because I need to check many condition

Comment: I have tried this comment already is there any other way to solve this problem ??

Comment: Yes same condition you can write in particular target column also. Use ternary operator like. (row1.column2 > 53 && row1.column2 < 100) && (!row1.column3.equals("POOL")) ? row1.column1 : null

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this....

arrange tmap settings as,

[image]

the condition in expression filter is

`!(row1.newColumn >53 && row1.newColumn<100)&&  (!row1.newColumn1 .equals("POOL"))`

then u can get required result..

here i take the following as input..

20;A

30;POOL

40;C

50;D

60;POOL

100;G

110;POOL

then i got result as,

[image]